# Automapper throwing "Input string not in correct format"

Tags: c#, constructor, automapper

I am trying to map two classes using automapper. The issue stems from my class having an encoded and unencoded state that changes the value of what is in the Id field from an obfuscated string to a string that can be parsed to an int, but I was under the impression that I'm handling that properly so that it shouldn't have a parsing issue.

Even though I decoding my state in `.BeforeMap()`, I still get an error saying that the input is the wrong type.

Classes

```cs
public class CompanyDTO {
  public CompanyDTO(){
    IsEncoded = true;
  }

  private int id { get; set; }
  public string Id
  {
      get
      {
          return GetIdValue(id);
      }
      set
      {
          id = SetIdValue(value);
      }
  }

  public bool IsEncoded {get; private set;}

  private string GetIdValue(string v){
    return isEncoded ? Utils.EncodeParam(v) : v.ToString(); // EncodeParam() performs encoding algorithm
  }

  private void SetIdValue(string v) {
    var intValue = v.TryParseInt(-1); // TryParseInt() custom extension to parse string to int else return parameter (-1)
    return intValue == -1 ? Utils.DecodeParam(v) : intValue; // DecodeParam() performs decoding algorithm
  }
}

public class CompanyVO {
  public CompanyVO() {}
  public CompanyVO(int id) {
    Id = id;
  }
  public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

Mappers

```cs
CreateMap<CompanyDTO, CompanyVO>()
  .BeforeMap((src, dst) => Utils.DecodeState(src)) // DecodeState() toggles IsEncoded to false
  .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id.TryParseInt(-1));

CreateMap<CompanyVO, CompanyDTO>()
  .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id.ToString());
```

Implementation

```cs
public void AddCompany(CompanyDTO company) {
  Mapper.Map<CompanyVO>(company); // Error: Input string was not in a correct format
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the wrong constructor is getting used by automapper and you have to specify which contructor to use by using `.ConstructUsing()` in the map configuration.

This is the current order of events that automapper takes:

1. Run constructor on destination type (I'm not certain how automapper chooses which one to run)

```
public CompanyVO(int id) { // Error: passed id is the encoded string, not the decoded version and not an int
  Id = id;
}
```

2. Run `.BeforeMap()`
3. Run mappers

The error can be resolved by specifying which constructor to use in the automapper.

```cs
CreateMap<CompanyDTO, CompanyVO>()
  .BeforeMap((src, dst) => Utils.DecodeState(src))
  .ConstructUsing(src => new CompanyVO()) // set constructor to the parameter-less one
  .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id.TryParseInt(-1));
```

My use-case allowed me to use the contructor without any parameters, though I could just have easily done this too:

```cs
CreateMap<CompanyDTO, CompanyVO>()
  .ConstructUsing(src => {
    Utils.DecodeState(src)
    return new CompanyVO(src.Id.TryParseInt(-1))
  })
  .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id.TryParseInt(-1));
```